# Zero cart price Issue in M2 ADD TO CART rest API in case of new customers

Tags: magento2, rest-api

**I'm working on M2 rest API's. I'm getting zero price issue in the same API.**

**How to re-create issue:**

```
1. Create new customer through rest API.
2. Login with the registered customer.
3. Now add the product to cart.
4. Now check the cart info through rest API URL.

Now cart showing zero price with zero total.

If you again add a new product or same product again. The correct price will be displayed.

The zero price issue always comes only in case of new customers. 

Request URL with parameters:
storeurl/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
SKU, qty, user_id
```

**Please check screenshots of the response:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and fixed it on the Magento side with following plugin

```
// app/code/Custom/Rest/Plugin/Model/Quote/Item/RepositoryPlugin.php

<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Dmytro Portenko
 * Date: 10/16/18
 * Time: 10:36 PM
 */
namespace Custom\Rest\Plugin\Model\Quote\Item;
class RepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }
    public function beforeSave(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository $subject,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem
    )
    {
        $cartId = $cartItem->getQuoteId();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quote->getShippingAddress();
    }
}

// app/code/Custom/Rest/etc/di.xml

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="customRestRepository" type="Custom\Rest\Plugin\Model\Quote\Item\RepositoryPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

After create a new cart by API, **POST** a cart address by API `rest/V1/carts/mine/billing-address`, the POST body could be empty like below

```
{
    "address" :     {

    },

    "cartId" : "{the cartId get from the cart you created just now}"
}
```

then the problem will be solved.

---

More information you could get from [Products added to cart with REST API give total prices equal to zero](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2991)

Comment: My products API returns products, if i try with customer i am getting error, my url : http://192.168.1.65/anusthana/api/rest/customers error : https://snag.gy/0jbhTr.jpg  can u help me

Comment: @zus The error is lacking permission. You need pass a privilege user token when request the customer api.

Comment: I am new in API, can you pls give me a demo url. @key

Comment: @zus The official example:  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-customer.html , notice the `Authorization Bearer <admin token>`

Comment: Here is my token : https://snag.gy/9BqesT.jpg, then how can i proced?

Comment: My magento version 1.9.2.3

Comment: @zus Sorry, I didn't use api in version 1.9, you need google some guide or blog on the internet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84850/discussion-between-zus-and-key-shang).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to resolve this issue

> **step 1)** Go to file 'vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php'(override this
> file using preference don't make change in core files)
>
> **step 2)** Edit this function 'createEmptyCartForCustomer'.
>
> **step 3)** In try before saving quote line number 234 add below code

```
$quote->getBillingAddress();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like charm. +1

Comment: Hi @jyoti , Subtotal and Grand total fixed with this. But Tax is still coming as 0.00 Any suggestions?